# Is there an open list comparing food gums and their viscosity/usages?

Tags: emulsion, additives

Couldn't find a good index for gums/emulsifiers with potency/viscosity comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the scientific papers I've found must be purchased, but this one is interesting:

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3551143/

Comment: I found this one too... It's partial though ...

Comment: nice!  i need similar with tolerances for freezing/thawing